# downloading issue in php .. return invalid file?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [try to download file and getting invalid file in response in core php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542203/try-to-download-file-and-getting-invalid-file-in-response-in-core-php)

```
$filename=gallery/downloads/poster/large/h.jpg
```

path to download file is correct but don't know why it give invalid file in return ...

```
 $filename = $_GET["filename"]; 
 $buffer = file_get_contents($filename);

    /* Force download dialog... */
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    /* Don't allow caching... */
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

    /* Set data type, size and filename */
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    /* Send our file... */
   echo $buffer;
```

if u have a better way then please share .... thanks in advance .

Comment: Why are you setting the Content-Type header **5** times?!

Comment: Please read the FAQ: [What if I don't get a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)

Comment: i m not get the answer ... it still give invalid file ... plz help me out of this ..

Comment: Again, read the FAQ for what to do if you don't get a good answer to  your question. Asking it again is not the right thing to do.

Comment: try looking at the php manual it has a basic example of what you try to accomplish ..

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be:

```
$filename = $_GET["filename"];
// Validate the filename (You so don't want people to be able to download
// EVERYTHING from your site...)

if (!file_exists($filename))
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    die();
}
// A check of filemtime and IMS/304 management would be good here

// Be sure to disable buffer management if needed
while(ob_get_level()) {
   ob_end_clean();
}

// Do not send out full path.
$basename = basename($filename);

Header('Content-Type: application/download');
Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$basename\"");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // Not really needed
Header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
Header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

readfile($filename);
```

That said, what does *"invalid file"* mean? Bad length? Zero length? Bad file name? Wrong MIME type? Wrong file contents? The meaning may be clear to you with everything under your eyes, but from our end it's far from obvious.

Comment: it die() in if(!file_exists)... not get the file from localhost...

Comment: OK, copying the answer to the previous question -- and editing it.